# How does one write Unit Tests for eBPF programs written in python via the BCC interface for eBPF?

Tags: python, unit-testing, ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I know this is a weird one, And I’m probably looking for help in a bleak topic since after days of scouring the net to no avail I decided to reach out to this community...

so I need to write unit tests for eBPF programs written in python with BCC

Any advice will be tremendously appreciated, even pointing me in the general direction of where i can further look for insights into solving the issue i am currently faced with

Here is a trivial example:

```
from bcc import BPF

# define BPF program
prog = """
int hello(void *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("Hello, World!\\n");
    return 0;
}
"""

# load BPF program
b = BPF(text=prog)
b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("clone"), fn_name="hello")

# header
print("%-18s %-16s %-6s %s" % ("TIME(s)", "COMM", "PID", "MESSAGE"))

# format output
while 1:
    try:
        (task, pid, cpu, flags, ts, msg) = b.trace_fields()
    except ValueError:
        continue
    print("%-18.9f %-16s %-6d %s" % (ts, task, pid, msg))
```

I need to unit test the C code and the python code independently to see that their both behaving as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unit test the Python logic in the usual way you would for Python. For the BPF part, there are two approaches:

- You use another Python program to load and trigger the BPF program you have written. To trigger your program, you can use `BPF_PROG_TEST_RUN` or you can attach it as planned and trigger the attach point (e.g., call `clone` if the program is attached to the clone(2) syscall). Admittedly, this approach looks almost more like end-to-end tests than unit tests.
- You split your BPF program into C functions in a header file. You write a C unit test that includes that header file and calls those functions with inputs to check. For that to work, you need to make sure that the C functions don't call anything BPF specific that could be compiled to a non-BPF backend. That can be a bit hard given maps and helpers.

Comment: If possible, please elaborate on your first point here  (I'll look at this kind of implementation later on in the project)

Comment: For the first point, see [this example](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/88b5edbdc98a50dedf9a911b8f1ab5a63c574767/tests/python/test_trace2.py) in the bcc repository for example. The first point is how bcc does it's "unit tests".

Comment: Cool, thanks, really seems like there's no quickstart to getting that depth of testing done, I will be working through the resources you gave me. Thanks!